# How do I package a shell script for distribution over GitHub?

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal

I wasn't quite sure where to begin my search for the answer to this question.

(I'm using Mac.)

Anyway, I have made a command line tool that runs some Ruby stuff. Basically, I added an executable file to a folder in my user directory, added permissions to let it run in Terminal. Then, I added the path to the executable to my `$PATH` variable. It all works completely fine for me. I can run it like this from my shell:

```
$ ngi controller
```

I uploaded the project to GitHub, and I've given users instructions to download it and use it the same way I do, but the download instruction are very convoluted (it's the best I could come up with):

```
~ $ mkdir .angular_init
~ $ cd .angular_init
~/.angular_init $ git clone https://github.com/joshbeam/angular_init.git
~/.angular_init $ cd angular_init/bin
~/.angular_init/angular_init/bin $ chmod 755 ngi
~/.angular_init/angular_init/bin $ export PATH=$PATH:~/.angular_init/angular_init/bin
```

Obviously, for tools like `rvm` and `npm`, you just magically download them and then they just work. **So how can I package my shell script to be easily "downloadable", and save the user the (confusing) effort of 6 shell lines?**

(If it helps at all, here's the [link to the repo](https://github.com/joshbeam/angular_init)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a few simplifying points you don't need to doubly-nest your directories and as you know `git clone` will create the directory it needs.

So

```
git clone https://github.com/joshbeam/angular_init.git .angular_init
```

will create and clone your repo directly into `.angular_init`.

You can also tell git that the file has execute permissions in the repo so it checks out that way instead of needing people to `chmod` it themselves. Simply change the permissions and add the file again then commit it. (You can use `git ls-tree HEAD -- <file>` in your working directory to see what git has the permissions as.)

That replaces the first five steps with just the git clone. Which leaves just two steps which is entirely reasonable.

Also the second step should likely be to put that sort of `PATH` modification line into the appropriate shell startup file rather than running it directly in the current shell session.

Alternatively, what the above lets you do is have people check the repository out to wherever they want and then link from there to a location that is already in their `PATH` directly.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. However, a couple questions: firstly, I ran git ls-tree HEAD -- bin/ngi, and the first part of the first line says `100755`. I assume that means it has the correct 755 permission?

Comment: Second question: the user can't run `ngi` (the tool) without the `PATH` first being set, so how would I set the `PATH` variable inside `ngi` if the user can't even access it yet? (`ngi` is the executable file that runs the Ruby code)

Comment: Yes, that means the permissions are 755 in the repo. Compare to another file and you'll see it says `100644` instead. I didn't say set `PATH` inside the `ngi` script. I said the directions should instruct the user to make the `PATH` modification in their existing (or newly created if necessary) shell startup files so that they persist for the future. As opposed to setting the `PATH` in the current shell session and not having it in any others later.

Comment: Okay, I see. You're talking about `~/.bash_profile`, or whatever it is for the user's machine, right?

Comment: Yes, that or the appropriate for `zsh`, etc. Assuming they don't like the script into a location that is *already* on their `PATH` (like `~/.bin` if they've set that up, etc.).